# jquery ui dialog form validation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

## Jquery UI dialog Form :

i have to create registration for a new website

### using :

1. jquery ui
2. php
3. mysql
4. Html5

### the problem :

1. cannot check if user or email exist.
2. **check_exist** function return the value of **notexist** and it always **not defined**
3. when is remove the notexist of if (bValid && notexist)  it work well
4. how can check if e mail exist on key up
5. how can disable register button if there's any error

---

#### ajax.php file source:

```
require_once '../global.php';
if ($_GET['do'] == "register") {
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $pass = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $ins = mysql_insert('users', array('u_name' => $name, 'password' => $pass));

    if ($ins) {
        $u_id = mysql_insert_id();
        $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
        $telephone = strip_tags($_POST['telephone']);
        $gender = strip_tags($_POST['gender']);
        $nationality = strip_tags($_POST['nationality']);
        $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);

        $ins2 = mysql_insert('patient_info', 
        array(
        'u_no' => $u_id, 
        'name' => $username, 
        'gender' => $gender,
        'nationality' => $nationality,
        'tel' => $telephone,
        'email' => $email
        ));
        if ($ins2) {
            echo "Welcome  you can login now :)";
        }
    } 
}
}

if ($_GET['do'] == "userexist") {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$result = mysql_query("select * from users where u_name ='" . $username . "'");

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
if ($row > 0) {
    echo 1;
}else{
    echo 0;
}
}
if ($_GET['do'] == "mailexist") {
$email = $_POST['email'];
$result = mysql_query("select * from patient_info where email ='" . $email . "'");

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
if ($row > 0) {
    echo 1;
}else{
    echo 0;
}
}
```

#### js file source:

```
$(function() {
$("#gender").buttonset();
var info = $('#notfi-info').hide();
$('#notfi-error').hide();
var name = $("#name"), email = $("#email"), password = $("#password"), username = $("#username"), telephone = $("#telephone"), gender = $('#gender input[name=gender]'), nationality = $("#nationality"), allFields = $([]).add(name).add(email).add(password).add(username).add(telephone).add(password).add(nationality), tips = $("#validateTips");

function getradio(r) {
    if (r.filter(':checked')) {
        if (r.filter(':checked').val() == "male" || r.filter(':checked').val() == "female") {
            return r.filter(':checked');
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function updateTips(t) {
    tips.text(t).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
    setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
    }, 500);
}

function checkLength(o, n, min, max) {
    if (o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min) {
        o.addClass("ui-state-error");
        updateTips("Length of " + n + " must be between " + min + " and " + max + ".");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function checkRegexp(o, regexp, n) {
    if (!( regexp.test(o.val()) )) {
        o.addClass("ui-state-error");
        updateTips(n);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function check_exist(x, y, z, k) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "inc/ajax.php?do=" + z,
        data : y + '=' + x.val(),
        cache : false,
        success : function(response) {
            if (response == "1") {
                x.addClass("ui-state-error");
                updateTips(k);
                return false;
            }
            if (response == "0") {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}

function subregform(form) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : form.attr("method"),
        url : form.attr("action"),
        data : form.serialize(),
        success : function(msg) {
            info.find(".info").text(msg);
            info.toggle();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
}


$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen : false,
    height : 450,
    width : 400,
    modal : true,
    buttons : {
        "Create an account" : function() {
            var bValid = true;
            allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
            bValid = bValid && checkLength(name, "login name", 3, 16);

            bValid = bValid && checkLength(email, "Email", 6, 80);
            bValid = bValid && checkLength(password, "Password", 5, 16);
            bValid = bValid && checkLength(username, "Username", 5, 16);
            bValid = bValid && checkLength(telephone, "Telephone", 7, 13);
            // bValid = bValid && checkLength(getradio, "Gender", 4, 5);
            bValid = bValid && checkLength(nationality, "Nationality", 3, 25);

            bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(telephone, /^[0-9]([0-9])+$/i, "Telephone may consist of 0-9 only.");
            // bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter.");
            // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
            bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com");
            // bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9");

            var notexist = true;

            notexist = notexist && check_exist(name, 'username', 'userexist', 'Login Name Already Exist!');
            notexist = notexist && check_exist(email, 'email', 'mailexist', 'E-Mail Already Exist!');
            if (bValid && notexist) {
                var form = $('#dialog-form form');
                subregform(form);

                // $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + username.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + telephone.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + gender.filter(':checked').val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + nationality.val() + "</td>" + "</tr>");
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }

        },
        Cancel : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");

        }
    },
    close : function() {
        allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
});

$("#create-user").button().click(function() {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have `=` it should be `:` and also make it an object:

```
function check_exist(x, y, z, k) {
jQuery.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "inc/ajax.php?do=" + z,
    data : {y:x.val()},
    cache : false,
    success : function(response) {
        if (response == "1") {
            x.addClass("ui-state-error");
            updateTips(k);
            return false;
        }
        if (response == "0") {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

}

Also and easier route would be to not include the `$_GET` variables at all and just stick to `if(isset($_POST[]))` so your code would look something like this:]

```
url : "inc/ajax.php",
    data : {do : z, y:x.val()},

if(isset($_POST['do'])){

  if($_POST['do']=="userexist")
}
```

Either way I believe your problem was with the `data` argument, however, there might be another issue with your mysql statement. Let me know if that change works...if it doesn't, open firebug or inspector, go to the network tab,  click the button to check if user exists and then see what the response is from the server.

Comment: `data :{do : z, y:x.val()}
`
give me 
do=userexist&y=ahmedfatehy

Then I tried this:

`data : {'do' : z, y:x.val()},`

and it return do=userexist&y=ahmed

then i try 
`data :'do='+ z +'&'+ y +'='+ x.val(),`
it return 
do=userexist&username=john

its working now but the main problem on :
notexist not true
          `var notexist = true;

            notexist = notexist && check_exist(name, 'username', 'userexist', 'Login Name Already Exist!');
            notexist = notexist && check_exist(email, 'email', 'mailexist', 'E-Mail Already Exist!');
            if (bValid && notexist) `

Answer (score 0):

`data :{do : z, y:x.val()}`

give me 
do=userexist&y=ahmedfatehy

Then I tried this:

`data : {'do' : z, y:x.val()},`

and it return do=userexist&y=ahmed

then i try 
`data :'do='+ z +'&'+ y +'='+ x.val(),`
it return 
do=userexist&username=john

its working now but the main problem on :
notexist not true

```
        var notexist = true;

        notexist = notexist && check_exist(name, 'username', 'userexist', 'Login Name Already Exist!');
        notexist = notexist && check_exist(email, 'email', 'mailexist', 'E-Mail Already Exist!');
        if (bValid && notexist) `
```

Comment: What is being returned from the server exactly?